# unable to fix project build React

Tags: build

error lru-cache@7.7.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12". Got "10.15.1"
error Found incompatible module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjgzs.png)

Comment: i tried to update the package lru-cache, but this message still doesn't give me build the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried updating the node? U need to update to a higher version of node (v12) probably.

You can download the latest stable node from here - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Or can use NVM (node version manager)